# Reset horizontal scroll after line motion

Tags: scrolling

- I currently satisfice by disabling `auto-hscroll-mode`, but I want it back.
- I know you can make it hscroll only the current line by setting it to `'current-line`. Doesn't fix the problem.

Problem: it's surprisingly hard to get back to the default unscrolled view unless you memorize a hotkey for `scroll-right`. Besides, pointwise motion should be sufficient (because it is in most modes), but in certain major modes like Eshell it cannot be relied on because `beginning-of-line` won't get you to the beginning of the line.

Result: you appear to be stuck in a hscrolled state, resulting in SX questions like [64393](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64393/how-to-scroll-to-the-beginning-of-the-line-in-emacs/).

I think user-friendly behavior would be that when `(current-column)` drops below `(window-width)`, i.e. the line can fit within the window, we evaluate `(scroll-right most-positive-fixnum)`, undoing the hscroll entirely.

I tried to advise `line-move-finish`, but it's not always the cause of line motion. How to always react to line motion?

Test case:

1. `emacs -Q`
2. `M-x eshell`
3. `M-x set-variable RET truncate-lines RET t RET`
4. Type a very long line so `auto-hscroll-mode` is invoked.
5. Try to get back a sane view...

Comment: I tried steps 1 to 3, and noticed that `eshell` defaults to `truncate-lines` being `nil`, which means that `auto-hscroll-mode` has no effect.  Are there any other settings that are missing from the test case that we should be using?  And, `(setq auto-hscroll-mode 'current-line)` should naturally be set *before* step 3.  Ideally, the test case should be from Emacs -Q (no user configuration).  Please also specify what numeric version of Emacs you are using, and whether you are in the terminal or the GUI version.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the `truncate-lines` thing. It should work in emacs -Q now.